# R ggplot2: Using 2 variables from one table but using the row above

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, dataframe

Is there a simple solution for this little problem:
The df looks like this e.g.

```
Date    V1    V2
u       A     X
v       B     Y
w       C     Z
```

Now I want to make a simple scatterplot with ggplot2 from V1 & V2 *BUT* I need the variable corresponding to the V1 variable to be the V2-1. So to match to V1 the value from V2 from the row above.

So in the scatterplot it should display B with X as one point and C with Y as one point. As this is not possible for the first row, it should not be included.

I do not want to chance neither the df nor create a new one. Is it possible to just "add" it as a layer in ggplot?

Comment: what happens to `Z`?

Comment: In the worst case I lose the values A and Z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1492)
df <- data.frame(date=letters,
                 v1=sample(100, 26),
                 v2=sample(100, 26))

# directly with base graphics
plot(df$v1[2:length(df$v1)], df$v2[1:(length(df$v2)-1)])

# ggplot2 needs a data.frame
ggplot(data=data.frame(v1=df$v1[2:length(df$v1)],
                       v2=df$v2[1:(length(df$v2)-1)]),
       aes(x=v1, y=v2)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: Thanks for this fast answer! How can I implement this solution when my ggplot looks like this: **ggplot(df[which(df$v1>0),], aes()...)**

Comment: that is prbly a new question (according to the way SO suggests these things work)